# Text from Server - JSON or Text Parsable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am receiving following text from a remote server - ideally would like to parse to JSON (however does not seem possible); or remain as string parsing to an array (seems no elegantly way to do it)

```
Text received: "[{"id":"5","role":"Admin","tracking":"1234567"}]"

Result required:

id=5
role=Admin
tracking=1234567
```

Question:

- is the text parsable to JSON? If not:
- would there be some elegant pattern to parse the text to an array? If not:
- should I bang on door of the remote server organization, and request changing returned text pattern?

Comment: `JSON.parse('[{"id":"5","role":"Admin","tracking":"1234567"}]')`. You can request and provide datatype json straight ahead to skip the parsing.

Comment: The text is arriving wrapped with double quotes: "[{"id":"5","role":"Admin","tracking":"1234567"}]". Is that JSON parsable -- or remove the outer double quotes to single quotes?

Comment: Just run `JSON.parse()` and you will find out. The `console.log()` falls back to double quotes no matter which you put.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger. That was extremely helpful.